# wordpress - output get_user_meta array as ul

Tags: arrays, wordpress, templates

I'm having trouble getting meta data from an array in a template.php - I have the following code:

```
<?php 
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $key = 'service_checkboxes'; 
  $single = false; 
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  echo $user_last; 
?>
```

This outputs: `Array`

I've also tried:

```
<?php 
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $key = 'service_checkboxes'; 
  $single = false; 
  $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
  print_r($user_last); 
?>
```

This outputs:  `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => pet_cat [1] => pet_dog [2] => pet_rabbit ) )`

What I'd like is

- Cats
- Dogs
- Rabbits

(These are the original labels on the checkboxes in the user profile)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: @lain-g, Please set `$single= true`. Then `print_r($user_last);` will return array like that `Array ( [0] => pet_cat [1] => pet_dog [2] => pet_rabbit ) `. Just iterate this using Foreach and you can easily generate the UL as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final answer

```
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $key = 'service_checkboxes'; 
    $single = true; 
    $user_last = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($user_last as $val){
       $formated_val = ucwords(str_replace('pet_','',$val));
      echo '<li>'.$formated_val.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```